# Copy parameters to object instance with getters and setters

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, getter-setter, ecmascript-5

I have this constructor object:

```
function Bindable(obj) {
    var prop;

    for (prop in obj) {
        this.__defineGetter__(prop, function () {
            return obj[prop];
        });

        this.__defineSetter__(prop, function (val) {
            obj[prop] = val;
        });
    }
}
```

Which is being called like so:

```
var model = new Bindable({
    name: 'Dave',
    level: 10,
    strength: 5
});
```

If I `console.log(model)`, the output is:

```
Bindable { name=5, level=5, strength=5 }
```

Why is the same value getting assigned to each of the properties in the constructor?

Comment: Why are you using the non standard and deprecated `__definePropert__` over the standard `Object.defineProperty` ?

Comment: Because that's news to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a closure that gets evaluated when the getter/setter functions execute, not when they are defined. At the time they execute, `prop` has the last value it was assigned during execution of the loop. You need to avoid creating a closure on `prop`. One way is with an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Instead of using this argument:

```
function () {
    return obj[prop];
}
```

use

```
(function(p) {
    return function() {
        return obj[p];
    };
}(prop));
```

Comment: That seems correct. Wouldn't `.bind`ing the handler instead of an IIFE provide for a simpler solution here?

Comment: I don't understand how `.bind`ing would work in this context. Please explain.

Comment: @davidkennedy85 [There you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Instead of wrapping in a closure explicitly, you set the value of `p` in a bind.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - You still need a function to use as an argument to `bind`. You also need to provide a `this` argument (likely `null`), which just adds code clutter. Like David, I don't see how `bind` provides a simplification.

Comment: Current code: `(function(p) { return function() { return obj[p];};}(prop));`. New code `function(p){ return obj[p]}.bind(null,prop);`. You judge.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, this should work for you.

[Same principle as explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202800/592253) by @[Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)

But now we have a reusable function `createGetterSetter` which uses the ECMA5 method [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for defining the [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters), as pointed out by  @[Benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum).

It is also using the ECMA5 [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of `for..in` that you used.

I think this is a little tidier than the solution Ted suggested (everyone has their preference).

The only part that I am unsure about room for improvement is `var self = this;`

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/*global console */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function createGetterSetter(object, map, prop) {
        Object.defineProperty(object, prop, {
            get: function () {
                return map[prop];
            },
            set: function (val) {
                map[prop] = val;
            }
        });
    }

    function Bindable(obj) {
        var self = this;

        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (prop) {
            createGetterSetter(self, obj, prop);
        });
    }

    var model = new Bindable({
        name: 'Dave',
        level: 10,
        strength: 5
    });

    console.log(model.name, model.level, model.strength);
}());
```

Output

```
Dave 10 5
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/YCX4h/)

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. I will leave Ted's answer as the selected answer though because it simply states what the problem was.